# Win32 Keyboard managing when key released while not focused

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keyboard-events

I have an input manager that nicely tracks the keyboard state via the messages

```
WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYUP
```

So i know when or not for example the left control is pressed.
However if the window loses focus and the key is released before it gains focus again, there will be no "key released" message.

This seems like a very awkward problem that everybody always has, so I feel like I am missing something. Right now I have a fix that just uses `GetKeyboardState` when the window gains focus. But it feels like this is a bit overkill.

Now I've also seen there is a "LowLevelKeyboardProc" which could help solve this by simply always detecting keys. But already simply from the name it feels like there are some downsides to using this (like slowing down all input for all apps?).

Is there some other solution that I am missing, and if not, which of these two would be a better approach?

Comment: "*So i know when or not for example the left control is pressed*" - you don't need a custom input manager for that, just use `Get(Async)KeyState()` instead.

Comment: _(like slowing down all input for all apps?)_: nobody types that fast BTW ;-)

Comment: @remy the 'GetAsyncKeystate()' seems the work in the context of the program. Is there a possibility to give a 2 different threads independant acces? Like when thread A calls it, the last call by A (and only A) counts as the last call.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Low-level hooks are *insanely* costly. They are executed in sequence, and every single one incurs a context switch. It doesn't take exceedingly long before you notice: 100 hooks are sufficient to make me dizzy while typing, and a comment along the lines of *"Don't worry, you'll be way fine"* makes sure that—eventually—100 hooks run on everyone's system.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late but...

though there is no way to get notified wether a key was released or not when window focus was lost, you are notified by WM_KILLFOCUS if the focus was lost.
if you tracked which keys were pressed, that would allow you to properly call a release procedure to handle this problem.

Answer (score -2):

You need to look up the MSDN documentation for SetWindowsHookEx. Essentially what you need to do use this function with a callback procedure (that is part of your application) that gets run when the key state changes.

Comment: The [Raw Input API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx) is usually preferred over `SetWindowHookEx()`.  [Even MSDN says so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx): "*In most cases where the application needs to use low level hooks, it should monitor raw input instead. This is because raw input can asynchronously monitor mouse and keyboard messages that are targeted for other threads more effectively than low level hooks can.*"